# Xamarin.iOS - UITableView with more cells than can fit in Designer

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

In my Xamarin Studio storyboard, I have created a Table View (UITableView) that has one section containing a bunch of table view cells (static content). I need 6 rows (cells) but the 6th one does not fit the display area of the view controller. I can see this cell in the designer but I cannot drag anything on it as it is somehow placed outside of the view controller (under it).

For clarity, I am attaching an image explaining the situation.

http://share.pho.to/7WKSL/i6/original

I am wondering if it is possible to add more cells than the view area can hold as in my scenario... or am I now forced to place controls at runtime ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug by the Xamarin team. The solution is to use the Interface Builder of XCode for this particular task.